# Extraer números de los meses de una columna con fechas (cadenas) y substituirlo por su nombre

Tags: python, pandas, date

En un DataFrame he creado una columna Month, donde he sacado el número del mes de otra columna que tenía formato 2015.06.12. Del .06. sacado, lo he convertido en número con un:

```
str.extract('(\.\d{2}\.)')
```

Y he quitado los dos puntos de esta manera:

```
str.extract('(\d{2})')
```

Ahora lo que quería hacer es cambiar esos números al mes que corresponde. He visto que es posible hacerlo con el módulo de calendar, lo he intentado hacer así:

```
def month(x):
  return calendar.month_name[x]

df['Month'] = df.Month.apply(month)
```

Pero me salta el error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

También decir que hay celdas NaN, que en principio las quiero dejar así.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema son los valores `NaN` como creo que sospechas. `NaN` se representa realmente como un float, por eso el error al usarlo como índice para `calendar.month_name`. De hecho, la columna con los `NaN` no la puedes convertir a `int` sin perder los propios `NaN`.

Puedes lidiar con ello de diferentes formas, siguiendo tu razonamiento, una muy simple es comprobar en la función si el valor recibido (`x`) es o no un valor `NaN`. Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar


df = pd.DataFrame({"Fecha": ("2015.01.12", 
                             "2015.02.12",
                             "2015.03.12",
                             "not a date",
                             "2015.09.12")}
                  )

df["Month"] = df["Fecha"].str.extract('\.(\d{2})\.').astype(np.float)

def month(x):
    return calendar.month_name[int(x)] if not np.isnan(x) else np.nan

df['Month'] = df.Month.apply(month)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>
>         Fecha       Month
> 0  2015.01.12       enero
> 1  2015.02.12     febrero
> 2  2015.03.12       marzo
> 3  not a date         NaN
> 4  2015.09.12  septiembre
> ```

No obstante, yo no me complicaría tanto con regex y `calendar`, puedes en principio hacer esto con pandas de forma vectorizada con solo convertir las cadenas con las fechas a tipo `DateTime` y hacer uso del método [`pandas.Series.dt.month_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html):

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({"Fecha": ("2015.01.12", 
                             "2015.02.12",
                             "2015.03.12",
                             "not a date",
                             "2015.09.12")}
                  )

df['Mes'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'], format='%Y.%m.%d', errors="coerce")
               .dt.month_name(locale='es_ES.utf8')
               )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>             Fecha         Mes
>     0  2015.01.12       Enero
>     1  2015.02.12     Febrero
>     2  2015.03.12       Marzo
>     3  not a date         NaN
>     4  2015.09.12  Septiembre
> ```

No se que idioma quieres para los nombres de los meses, pero puedes modificarlo especificando la localización que quieras mediante el argumento `locale`. Por defecto es `en_US`.